# File.Open used with FileShare.ReadWrite and still get error

Tags: c#

I am creating zip file and for that I am getting files from directory and processing them.

when processing I am using File.open with FileShare.ReadWrite.but I am getting following error when accessing any file.

> "The process cannot access the file 'myfile.ext' because it is being
>   used by another process."

anyone knows why I am getting this error even if FileShare.ReadWrite is there?

here is my code

```
string targateFolder = Path.GetTempPath() + @"xml\";

            String[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(targateFolder);                

            using (ZipOutputStream s = new
            ZipOutputStream(File.Create(targateFolder + txtId.Text + ".zip")))
            {
                s.SetLevel(9); // 0-9, 9 being the highest compression

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                foreach (string file in filenames)
                {

                    if (file.Equals(targateFolder + txtId.Text + ".zip"))
                    {

                        ZipEntry entry = new
                        ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));

                        entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        s.PutNextEntry(entry);

                        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            int sourceBytes;
                            do
                            {
                                sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0,
                                buffer.Length);

                                s.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);

                            } while (sourceBytes > 0);


                        }

                    }

                }
                s.Finish();
                s.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not abot permissions. There is already an open stream for your file:

```
File.Create(targateFolder + txtId.Text + ".zip")
```

`File.Create` creates the file and opens a stream so you can't access your file before closing it.

Comment: so how can I close file ?